# Python slow on fetchone, hangs on fetchall

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm writing a script to SELECT query a database and parse through ~33,000 records. Unfortunately I'm running into problems at the `cursor.fetchone()`/`cursor.fetchall()` phase of things.

I first tried iterating through the cursor a record at a time like so:

```
# Run through every record, extract the kanji, then query for FK and weight
printStatus("Starting weight calculations")
while True:
    # Get the next row in the cursor
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row == None:
        break

    # TODO: Determine if there's any kanji in row[2]

    weight = float((row[3] + row[4]))/2
    printStatus("Weight: " + str(weight))
```

Based on the output of `printStatus` (it prints out a timestamp plus whatever string is passed to it), the script took approximately 1 second to process each row. This lead me to believe that the query was being re-run each time the loop iterated (with a LIMIT 1 or something), as it took ~1 second for the same query to run once in something like SQLiteStudio [i]and[/i] return all 33,000 rows. I calculated that, at that rate, it would take around 7 hours to get through all 33,000 records.

Instead of sitting through that, I tried to use cursor.fetchall() instead:

```
results = cursor.fetchall()

# Run through every record, extract the kanji, then query for FK and weight
printStatus("Starting weight calculations")
for row in results:
    # TODO: Determine if there's any kanji in row[2]

    weight = float((row[3] + row[4]))/2
    printStatus("Weight: " + str(weight))
```

Unfortunately, the Python executable locked up at 25% CPU and ~6MB of RAM when it got to the `cursor.fetchall()` line. I left the script running for ~10 minutes, but nothing happened.

Is ~33,000 returned rows (about 5MB of data) too much for Python to grab at once? Am I stuck iterating through one at a time? Or is there something I can do to speed things up?

**EDIT: Here's some console output**

```
12:56:26.019: Adding new column 'weight' and related index to r_ele
12:56:26.019: Querying database
12:56:28.079: Starting weight calculations
12:56:28.079: Weight: 1.0
12:56:28.079: Weight: 0.5
12:56:28.080: Weight: 0.5
12:56:28.338: Weight: 1.0
12:56:28.339: Weight: 3.0
12:56:28.843: Weight: 1.5
12:56:28.844: Weight: 1.0
12:56:28.844: Weight: 0.5
12:56:28.844: Weight: 0.5
12:56:28.845: Weight: 0.5
12:56:29.351: Weight: 0.5
12:56:29.855: Weight: 0.5
12:56:29.856: Weight: 1.0
12:56:30.371: Weight: 0.5
12:56:30.885: Weight: 0.5
12:56:31.146: Weight: 0.5
12:56:31.650: Weight: 1.0
12:56:32.432: Weight: 0.5
12:56:32.951: Weight: 0.5
12:56:32.951: Weight: 0.5
12:56:32.952: Weight: 1.0
12:56:33.454: Weight: 0.5
12:56:33.455: Weight: 0.5
12:56:33.455: Weight: 1.0
12:56:33.716: Weight: 0.5
12:56:33.716: Weight: 1.0
```

And here's the SQL query:

```
//...snip (it wasn't the culprit)...
```

The output of EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN from SQLiteStudio:

```
0   0   0   SCAN TABLE r_ele AS re USING COVERING INDEX r_ele_fk (~500000 rows)
0   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1   0   0   SEARCH TABLE re_pri USING INDEX re_pri_fk (fk=?) (~10 rows)
0   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 2
2   0   0   SEARCH TABLE ke_pri USING INDEX ke_pri_fk (fk=?) (~10 rows)
2   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 3
3   0   0   SEARCH TABLE k_ele USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (value=?) (~7 rows)
3   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 4
4   0   0   SEARCH TABLE k_ele USING COVERING INDEX idx_k_ele (fk=?) (~10 rows)
0   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 5
5   0   0   SEARCH TABLE k_ele USING COVERING INDEX idx_k_ele (fk=?) (~10 rows)
0   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 6
6   0   0   SEARCH TABLE re_pri USING INDEX re_pri_fk (fk=?) (~10 rows)
0   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 7
7   0   0   SEARCH TABLE ke_pri USING INDEX ke_pri_fk (fk=?) (~10 rows)
7   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 8
8   0   0   SEARCH TABLE k_ele USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (value=?) (~7 rows)
8   0   0   EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 9
9   0   0   SEARCH TABLE k_ele USING COVERING INDEX idx_k_ele (fk=?) (~10 rows)
```

Comment: Have you tried just iterating over the cursor: `for row in cursor: ...` ?

Comment: There is no way that `fetchone` (or iterating) can cause it to re-run the query each time. The `cursor` object generally doesn't even _know_ the query that it ran. So, whatever your problem is, that isn't it.

Comment: Also, as a side note: use `if row is None:`, not `if row == None:`. In most cases it doesn't really make any difference, but it's more idiomatic (and it's also a little faster, and on the rare occasions when it _does_ make a difference it's going to be the one you want).

Comment: Anyway… are you sure you're running the exact same query against the exact same database in Python and in SQLite Studio? Something silly like binding the wrong argument to a parameter in a LIKE can turn something from milliseconds to hours…

Comment: @JonClements: I updated the script to try that but it's still slow as heck. I'm seeing similar performance to using cursor.fetchone(). I've updated the question to show some output.

Comment: Why did you open this question *without* showing the SQL statement executed? AFAIK a lot of people use SQL databases(sqlite and none), and don't have many problems about performances even with really big datas, so I suspect that *you* are doing something wrong(in SQL).

Comment: @Bakuriu has a really good point - show us the SQL :)

Comment: While you're fetching the query, some DDL will also be helpful.

Comment: The query's been added. I didn't think to add it because the script runs in an acceptable amount of time in SQLiteStudio. And before you say it, yes, I know there's some redundancy, but I can't use column aliases in WHERE clauses so I have to repeat some stuff to make sure everything sorts properly. I'm having to massage the data to get it into a form I can easily parse through for these calculations.

Comment: What are the SQLite versions in SQLite Studio and Python? (`SELECT sqlite_verson();`)

Comment: SQLite is version 3.7.16.1, and Python is 2.7.3. I thought I was using Python 3.x+, maybe upgrading will help?

Comment: @MasterKale I think the question wasn't what Python version it was... But what SQLite version Python 2.7.3... `import sqlite3; sqlite3.sqlite_version`.... 2.7.3 should give you `3.7.13`

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. My installation of Python returned `3.6.21`.

Comment: Okay - not sure what @CL. thinks how that information may be of use... but they've got it ;)

Comment: If the same query on the same database file works differently, then the 3.7 SQLite optimizer has become better. Please show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) in SQLite Studio.

Comment: @CL.: I've edited the question to include the output from EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN.

Comment: Have you tried using `fetchmany`? How long does it take to fetch 10 rows? 100? 1000?

Comment: I'm not sure if this'll help, but I retrieved the number of returned rows immediately after running the query. Python reported that it retrieved 20 rows even though, if left alone, it would continue to go through all 33,000 records.

Comment: @HampusNilsson: I tried iterating through the records using fetchmany(100) - there was a 60-70 second pause in between each fetch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite computes result records on the fly.
`fetchone` is slow because it has to execute all subqueries for each record in `r_ele`.
`fetchall` is even slower because it takes just as long as if you had executed `fetchone` for all records.

SQLite 3.7.13 estimates that all the lookups on the `value` column would be horribly slow, and therefore creates a temporary index for this query.
You should create a permanent index so that it can be used by SQLite 3.6.21:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_k_ele_value ON k_ele(value);
```

If that does not help, update to a Python with a newer SQLite version, or use another database library with a newer SQLite version built-in, such as [APSW](http://code.google.com/p/apsw/).

Comment: This wasn't a Python issue at all, it was a lack of proper indices. After creating the above index, Python chewed through all 33,000 records in about 2.5 seconds, and execution time in SQlite Studio went from around 1.75 seconds to 0.0006 seconds.