# Python/Hive interface slow with fetchone(), hangs with fetchall()

Tags: python, hive

I have a python script that is querying HiveServer2 using pyhs2, like so:

```
import pyhs2;
conn = pyhs2.connect(host=localhost,
               port=10000,
               user='user',
               password='password',
               database='default');

cur = conn.cursor();
cur.execute("SELECT name,data,number,time FROM table WHERE date = '2014-01-01' AND number in (1,5,6,22) ORDER BY name,time ASC");

line = cur.fetchone();
while line is not None:
   <do some processing, including writing to stdout>
   .
   .
   .
   line = cur.fetchone();
```

I have also tried using fetchall() instead of fetchone(), but that just seems to hang forever.

My query runs just fine and returns ~270 million rows. For testing, I dumped the output from Hive into a flat, tab-delimited file and wrote the guts of my python script against that, so I didn't have to wait for the query to finish everytime I ran. My script that reads the flat file will finish in ~20 minutes.  What confuses me is that I don't see that same performance when I directly query Hive. In fact, it takes about 5 times longer to finish processing. I am pretty new to Hive, and python so maybe I am making some bone-headed error, but examples that I see online show a set up such as this. I just want to iterate through my Hive return, getting one row at a time as quickly as possible, much like I did using my flat file. Any suggestions?

P.S. I have found this question that sounds similar:

[Python slow on fetchone, hangs on fetchall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343445/python-slow-on-fetchone-hangs-on-fetchall)

but that ended up being a SQLite issue, and I have no control over my Hive set up.

Comment: Have you tried hive -e 'select name, data .....' > file.out? Does this give the same performance

Comment: Yes, I have tried that in the days since I posted this question. I should have updated it with what I have tried. This is a good suggestion as I have received the best performance with something like `hive -e 'select name,data...' | python script.py`

Comment: In the interest of telling the story of my experience and helping as much as possible I will say that I chose not to use this pyhs2 library since I got the best performance just piping to my program's standard in. I avoided dumping the data to a file that I then process since this would be run of I/O on the HDD.  Also, I've heard that hive writes a file in the process of returning data anyway.  I am now looking into HBase, but I would like to get Hive working the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using fetchmany().

That would be the DBAPI answer for pulling data in chunks (bigger one, where the overhead is an issue, and smaller than all rows, where memory is an issue).

Comment: Looking at the source code, fetchmany simply calls fetchone in a loop. So it is going to suffer the same performance issues, possibly worse as it appends all the data to an array.

Comment: I'm no python expert but looking at the source code pyhs2 module just does not look efficient to me. It puts a lock on the cursor object in fetchmany but then locks and releases it every time in fetchone. Looks like a fairly basic mistake to me where functionality that should be done once outside a loop is done within it.